# javax.inject.Current cannot be found

Tags: jsf, netbeans, cdi

I am trying to learn JSF using netbeans with glass fish.
Everything is up to date. From the sdk to netbeans. I am following some examples from a book published in 2009.

In out of the examples, the writer has used the @Current annotations and imported javax.inject.Current.

When i try out the code using netbeans, netbeans throws an error. I have added the java EE 7 library but nothing doing.

In your answer(s) 1- Explain why netbeans cannot find the class and 2- Give step by step procedures for adding the class to my project.

Here's the code I'm using.

`    package hello;

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
 import javax.inject.Named;
 import javax.inject.Inject.Current;

 @Named
 @RequestScoped
 public class QuoteRequest {

   private String symbol;
   @Current
   private StockService service;
   private Date quoteDate = new Date();

   public QuoteRequest() {

   }

   public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
  }

  public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

 public double getStockValue(){
    return service.getStockValue(this);
 }

 public Date getQuoteDate() {
    return quoteDate;
}

 public void setQuoteDate(Date qouteDate) {
    this.quoteDate = qouteDate;
 }
```

}
`

Comment: You tagged the question using Spring. The `javax.inject` package is from Java EE and that static interface `javax.inject.Current` can be located nowhere in Java EE 7. Perhaps, it still exists to some extent with another name. Perhaps, it is `@Default`. Why not migrate towards learning new things avoiding those old 2009 things?

Comment: I have removed the Spring tag. Is there a current book you'd recommend?

Comment: Except for Java SE, I never read any book as of now other than just official documentations and/or official tutorials :) So I do not precisely know about any good books other than them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things

1. Use @Inject annotation from javax.inject package instead of @Current annotation as the book says.
2. Make sure you have an empty beans.xml file in your WEB-INF folder. This file is important to treat your beans as CDI beans.